# Match 1:many on excel

Tags: excel, file, csv, match, vlookup

I have an excel file that contains links with unique IDs, an example is as follows -

```
file://allthefiles/1234/picture1.jpg
file://allthefiles/1234/picture2.jpg
file://allthefiles/1233/flower.txt
file://allthefiles/1237/work.doc
```

I have another CSV file, that contains (only one instance of) these unique IDs -

```
Type    IDs    
 x      1233
 y      1237
 z      1234
```

What I want to get is -

```
Type     IDs    links
  x      1233   file://allthefiles/1233/flower.txt
  y      1237   file://allthefiles/1237/work.doc
  z      1234   file://allthefiles/1234/picture1.jpg
  z      1234   file://allthefiles/1234/picture2.jpg
```

So as you can see, since there are two different values for '1234' another value field was created.

I tried to match via excel, but this is not working. How can I do this using  vlookup?

Comment: What do you want Excel to do when you encounter multiple matches?

Comment: You could parse, since all files start with file://allthefiles/. Remove that part and then do the match. Should work like a charm.

Comment: For many matches, I would want that many rows created and the links put there

Comment: I would parse, but i need the entire link to be there

Comment: you would only parse for your match, you can still put your whole link afterwards. Or add it before, since it's always the same

Comment: But there are other types, and that mapping cannot change

Comment: hello, i need help.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be practical if there are many rows in the CSV file but is for the three that are shown. This assumes links are in ColumnC starting in Row1 and a copy of the CSV file's three rows is in the sheet in a table named CSVfile with its first column named CSVc1. In A1:

```
=INDEX(CSVc1,IFERROR(SIGN(FIND(1233,C1)),IFERROR(2*SIGN(FIND(1237,C1)),3)))
```

in B1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,CSVfile,2,0)
```

with both copied down to suit and ColumnA:C sorted by Column A A to Z then by Column B Smallest to Largest.